# CrudRepository not deleting row

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have created a plan class like so

Plan:

```
@Entity(name = "Plan")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class PlanEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int planId;

    private String planName;

    private BigDecimal pBenefitMax;

    private LocalDate pStartDate;

    private LocalDate pEndDate;

    private int pCompanyId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dPlanId")
    private List<DentalAgreementEntity> dentalAgreementEntities;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pPlanId")
    private List<PatientEntity> patientEntities;
}
```

The Patient Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Patient")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class PatientEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int patientId;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String patientEmail;

    private String patientPhone;

    private LocalDateTime dateOfBirth;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tPatientId")
    private List<TransactionEntity> transactionEntities;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "aPatientId")
    private List<AppointmentEntity> appointmentEntities;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pPlanId")
    private PlanEntity planEntity;

}
```

And the Agreement Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity(name = "DentalAgreement")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class DentalAgreementEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer agreementId;

    private BigDecimal percentage;

    private Integer dPlanId;

    private String dAdaCode;
}
```

The PlanRepository looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface PlanRepository extends CrudRepository<PlanEntity, Integer> {
}
```

And I am able to successfully save plan entities easily. However, if I try to delete a PlanEntity, like so:

```
public void deleteCompanyPlan(PlanEntity planEntity){
    planRepository.delete(planEntity);
}
```

Though no errors are thrown, when I check the database, the row is not deleted. I have tried making the class serializable, just using the "deleteById()" method, and many other things but I cannot delete a Plan through the Spring implementation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it actually execute any SQL? If you have not done so already, try setting property spring.jpa.show-sql=true to see if it outputs anything when you do the delete?

Comment: It's a long shot, but have you tried changing the ID type from `int` to `Integer` ? From the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-pojo-identifier): We recommend that you declare consistently-named identifier attributes on persistent classes and that you use a nullable (i.e., non-primitive) type.

Comment: It does not actually execute any SQL. I also tried changing the PK to Integer, and that did not help either.

Comment: You need to add `@Service`/`@Component` annotation from class you're calling `deleteCompanyPlan()` and/or class itself that defines `deleteCompanyPlan()`

Comment: You cannot modify data without a transaction... Judging from your method there is no `@Transactional` on there (or the comopnent). Hence nothing will be deleted.

Comment: ```planRepository.deleteById(3);``` a typo? ```planRepository.deleteById(planEntity.getPlanId());```

Comment: You don't need @Transactional on your Repository methods. Also there's no need for @Service/@Component annotation. I'd recommend to set the hibernate logs to TRACE Level (In Spring "logging.level.org.hibernate: trace") and check the logs where the deletion should happen. I assume you need to set CASCADE.DELETE on your @ ManyToOne annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed by removing the FetchType.LAZY and CascadeType.All from a parent entity.

```
@Entity(name = "Company")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
public class CompanyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int companyId;

    private String companyName;

    private String companyNumber;

    private String companyEmail;

    private String companyAddress;

    private String companyCity;

    private String companyState;

    private String companyZip;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "pCompanyId")
    private List<PatientEntity> patientEntities;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "pCompanyId")
    private List<PlanEntity> planEntities;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CompanyEntity{" +
                "companyId=" + companyId +
                ", companyName='" + companyName + '\'' +
                ", companyNumber='" + companyNumber + '\'' +
                ", companyEmail='" + companyEmail + '\'' +
                ", companyAddress='" + companyAddress + '\'' +
                ", companyCity='" + companyCity + '\'' +
                ", companyState='" + companyState + '\'' +
                ", companyZip='" + companyZip + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain "How" FetchType.LAZY and CascadeType.All blocking the deletion?

Comment: Don't know. But I noticed Hibernate making a Company Table Query whenever I called the "delete" method, so I decided to try changing the Company Entity.